# R readr: Reading text files with variable metadata headers

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

Is there a nice way within **readr** to read text files that have metadata headers of variable lengths? So far, I am manually deleting the header, but would definitely prefer to not change my raw data in any way.

I am aware that I can **skip** and **comment** specific lines with e.g. **read_delim**. However, these options are not working here. I attached a shortened example of one of my text files. The metadata starts with **/*** and ends with ***/**. I wonder if there may be an option to skip everything until ***/** appears (as in **fread**)? I tried reading my files with **fread** instead, but ran into different problems then (i.e. error message that column names can not be duplicated). Guess I could figure it out with **fread**, though. But I'm very curious if there's an option within **readr**.

```
sample <- c("/* DATA DESCRIPTION:", "Citation:\tName (2015) Title", "Coverage:\tLATITUDE: 44.360000 * LONGITUDE: -26.543333", 
"Parameter(s):\tDEPTH, sediment/rock [m] (Depth) * GEOCODE", 
"\tAGE [ka BP] (Age) * GEOCODE", "\tGlobigerinella aequilateralis [%] (G. aequilateralis) * PI: Name * METHOD/DEVICE: Counting >150 Âµm fraction", 
"\tGlobigerina bulloides [%] (G. bulloides) * PI: Name * METHOD/DEVICE: Counting >150 Âµm fraction", 
"\tDeuterammina grahami [%] (D. grahami) * PI: Name * METHOD/DEVICE: Counting >150 Âµm fraction", 
"Size:\t8188 data points", "*/", "Depth [m]\tAge [ka BP]\tG. aequilateralis [%] (Counting >150 Âµm fraction)\tG. bulloides [%] (Counting >150 Âµm fraction)\tD. grahami [%] (Counting >150 Âµm fraction)", 
"0.0075\t2.23\t0.5\t23.0\t1.5", "0.0550\t3.64\t1.7\t20.8\t1.3", 
"0.0850\t4.53\t1.1\t22.3\t3.4")

 [1] "/* DATA DESCRIPTION:"                                                                                                                                              
 [2] "Citation:\tName (2015) Title"                                                                                                                                       
 [3] "Coverage:\tLATITUDE: 44.360000 * LONGITUDE: -26.543333"                                                                                                             
 [4] "Parameter(s):\tDEPTH, sediment/rock [m] (Depth) * GEOCODE"                                                                                                          
 [5] "\tAGE [ka BP] (Age) * GEOCODE"                                                                                                                                      
 [6] "\tGlobigerinella aequilateralis [%] (G. aequilateralis) * PI: Name * METHOD/DEVICE: Counting >150 Âµm fraction"                                                    
 [7] "\tGlobigerina bulloides [%] (G. bulloides) * PI: Name * METHOD/DEVICE: Counting >150 Âµm fraction"                                                                 
 [8] "\tDeuterammina grahami [%] (D. grahami) * PI: Name * METHOD/DEVICE: Counting >150 Âµm fraction"                                                                    
 [9] "Size:\t8188 data points"                                                                                                                                            
[10] "*/"                                                                                                                                                                
[11] "Depth [m]\tAge [ka BP]\tG. aequilateralis [%] (Counting >150 Âµm fraction)\tG. bulloides [%] (Counting >150 Âµm fraction)\tD. grahami [%] (Counting >150 Âµm fraction)"
[12] "0.0075\t2.23\t0.5\t23.0\t1.5"                                                                                                                                          
[13] "0.0550\t3.64\t1.7\t20.8\t1.3"                                                                                                                                          
[14] "0.0850\t4.53\t1.1\t22.3\t3.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler way to do this.  Here is one approach using `readtext`, `purrr`,`dplyr` and `read.table`. Code works for reading a single text file at the moment.

```
library(readtext)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
```

> Identify file name

```
file_name <- "test.txt"
```

> use `map_dfr` from `purrr` package and `readtext` to read text files into a dataframe, use `gsub` to remove metadata in the text between */ and */, use `mutate` to save the remaining text in `clean_text` variable. Use `read.table` to read `clean_text`

```
df  <- map_dfr(file_name,readtext) %>% mutate(clean_text=gsub("^.*/*...*/","",text)) %>% select(clean_text) %>%
  as.character() %>% read.table(header = TRUE, sep = ",",text=.)
```

Validated using the following simple test data in file test.txt:
/* metadata to skip */ \n
col1, col2, col3, col4\n
data11, data12, data13, data14\n
data21, data22, data23, data24\n

> Output looks like this:

```
> df
    col1    col2    col3    col4
1 data11  data12  data13  data14
2 data21  data22  data23  data24
```